# Getting line count of all files in project in sorted order.(Bash terminal)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I have this folder contiaining a lot of *.cpp and *.h files. I want to get a line count of all the files and display them to the screen in sorted order of line count.

I know `wc -l *.h *.cpp` will display all the file names with line count, but not in sorted order.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `wc -l *.h *.cpp | sort -n`. One job (sort), one tool (`sort`).

Comment: Since this is source code, I would use `sloccount` for this instead of `wc`.

Comment: Wow! +1 for this fantastic resource!

Comment: In case you're handling a case with subdirectories (java for example) the following command does the same recursively.
`find . -name *.java | xargs wc -l | sort -n`